# Set css file for default skin

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created css style sheet based on caspian.css. My question is how I can load the new css skin as default skin?

And also how I can change the skins during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the stylesheet directly to the [`Scene`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets%28%29) or to any [`Parent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getStylesheets%28%29) to apply it to the node and all decendants. Both classes have a method `getStylesheets()` that returns a [`ObservableList<java.lang.String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html), that contains the `URL`s of the stylesheets applied to the object. Modify this list!

If you use fxml, you can specify the stylesheet there too (Of course this will only set the a initial stylesheet).

This is an example how to add the stylesheet at the creation of the scene. Of course you can remove the stylesheet from the list at any time and add another. `Style.css` is the stylesheet I want to add here and to `a.b` the package that contains the stylesheet.

```
// Load some content from some fxml file; Style.css not added there
Parent parent = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(
       getClass().getResourceAsStream("MainFrame.fxml"));

// create scene with content
Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
// alternatively use Node.getScene() for any node to get the scene    

// add the stylesheet
scene.getStylesheets().add(
           getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("a/b/Style.css").toString());
// ...
```

`ObservableList<T>` extends `java.util.List<T>` and should be easy to use.

Note that the behaviour sometimes may not be quite as expected. e.g. the popup that shows, if you click on a combobox is no decendant of the combobox and the paths from these nodes to from the root node of the scene should have only the root node in common. Therefore the popup will not be styled, if you add the stylesheet to the Pane that contains the combobox (if this is not the root node of the scene).

The following picture contains a screenshot of a combobox with a styled popup. This only works, since the css-file was added to the scene instead of the AnchorPane, that contains the ComboBox. I used different css-classes for the items to color them. (The red rect and text is not part of my application of course)

[image: Combobox Popup]

These are the style classes i used

```
.indexed-cell.class-value-bad-1 {
    -fx-background-color: orange;
}

.indexed-cell.class-value-good-1 {
    -fx-background-color: forestgreen;
}

.indexed-cell.class-value-normal {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: One last thing. How I can do this with combo box and change it during run time?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: If you add the stylesheet to the scene, that's no problem, even with the popup (since the popup is part of the scene, but not a descendant of e.g. the AnchorPane from the fxml file). You can modify stylesheet list any time, and as the name ObservableList indicates, that should automatically apply the changes to the scene.